# Как делают программы с интерфейсом Windows XP SP3, Vista, 7 и т.д.?

Tags: windows, vista, visual-basic

Я очень хотел делать программы с интерфейсом Windows, с трудом нашёл Visual Basic и каково было моё разочарование, когда я узнал, что там кнопки (и другой интерфейс) какие-то 2d-шные (как Chemax) и под Windows 98, NT, и другие дряхлые системы. А это не то, что я хочу! Подскажите, на каком языке (в какой среде) делают приложения с интерфейсом Windows XP, Vista, 7, и другие современные, в которых интерфейс зависит от темы и кнопки. Короче, такие как Kaspersky Norton Win Doctor и т.д. и где взять учебники и как это делать лучше? Пожалуйста, поподробнее.

Comment: Возможно, вам будут интересны следующие темы: 

 * [Светящиеся кнопки в Delphi][1]
 * [Особые кнопки в CodeGear C++ Builder][2]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/38323/
  [2]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/32954/

Comment: Просто пишите в современных средах и все будет пучком. Для меня вообще открытие то, что Вы говорите, т.к. визуальные компоненты - лишь оболочки для стандартных виндовых элементов. И, следовательно, должны выглядеть соответственно версии операционной системы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это небось VB6? Помню, было такое дело.

1. Рядом с ЕХЕ-шником кладите файл `ИМЯEXE.manifest` примерно следующего содержания:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
   <assembly 
     xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"
     manifestVersion="1.0">
       <assemblyIdentity
          name="CiaoSoftware.Ciao.Shell.Contacts"
           processorArchitecture="x86"
           version="5.1.0.0"
           type="win32"/>
       <description>Windows Shell</description>
       <dependency>
           <dependentAssembly>
               <assemblyIdentity
                   type="win32"
                   name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
                   version="6.0.0.0"
                   processorArchitecture="x86"
                   publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
                   language="*"
               />
           </dependentAssembly>
       </dependency>
   </assembly>
   ```
2. ВАЖНО. Все ocx-контролы (и dll)? которые используются для создания интерфейса (при добавлении которых появляются всякие списки, тривью (treeview)) должны быть не ниже версии 6.0. Пояснение: такой ЕХЕшник нельзя собрать на ОС ниже ХР.

Или более продвинутый вариант - ставить Visual Studio 2003 и выше. Там это включается опцией в настройках формы и одной командой глобального объекта `Application`.

Comment: Спасибо ато я нигде не нашёл про это

Comment: Также можно добавить, что отдельный файл для манифеста не обязателен, его можно прикрепить в виде ресурса к exe / dll файлу в раздел `Manifest`